# How can I create a "non-linear" trajectory using jQuery.animate()?

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to animate an element from position A to position B, but I don't want it to go linearly between each point, I'd like to have kind of a "parabolic" trajectory.

Can I use jQuery.animate() at all?

Or should I be manually coding it from scratch using setInterval()?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a project

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/MoveTo-Bezier-Curve

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own "easing" functions on `jQuery.easing`, for instance, this function would approximate a sin curve over 90degrees

```
jQuery.easing.sin90 = function(p, n, firstNum, diff) {
    return Math.sin(p * Math.PI / 2) * diff + firstNum;
};
```

`p` is a number from 0-1 representing the percentage of the animation time, `n` is the actual time elapsed for this animation, and `firstNum` and `diff` are a little misleading, it appears as if at some point this would take a start / end value, but now all easing functions just normalize the `p` value so `firstNum = 0` and `diff = 1`

I put together [a simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/nfeZF/) showing using per property easing and some sin/cos functions to animate a div in circles using jQuery.

Comment: Nice! I"m going with the Bezier, since it seems more flexible, but it's great to know this can be done, thank you very much!